# Showing month name from users input using JS switch case

Tags: javascript, events, switch-statement

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type = "text" id="checkMonth" required='' min="1" max="12" maxlength="12">
    <p id="show"></p>
    <button id="showMonth">check</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('checkMonth').value); 
var m = '';
switch (a) {  
    case 1: m = 'Jan'; break;
    case 2: m = 'Feb'; break;
    case 3: m = 'Mar'; break;
    case 4: m = 'Apr'; break;
    case 5: m = 'May'; break;
    case 6: m = 'Jun'; break;
    case 7: m = 'Jul'; break;
    case 8: m = 'Aug'; break;
    case 9: m = 'Sep'; break;
    case 10: m = 'Oct'; break;
    case 11: m = 'Nov'; break;
    case 12: m = 'Dec'; break;
    default: break;
}
document.getElementById('showMonth').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = m;
});
```

Sorry for a bit noisy code . so I came around with this . But this still not working as it is showing undefined !! don't know why !!

Comment: Since it's not clear where you want to display month name so I'm assuming this to be a `<label id="month">`.

Also since you have `month` array and you know input will be in range of `1-12` you don't need any `switch case`.

JavaScript:
  
   ` document.getElementById("month").html(month[a-1]);`

Comment: ohh !! thank you ..i'll try that

Comment: but what if i don't have an array ! sorry if i didn't explain thoroughly .lets take it as .. i have a input field and a button . everytime user put some number in it 1-12 and with button click it will show the month name ? can you help me in that ?

Comment: document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "this is " + month[a - 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have month array and need to use switch case

JS:

```
let m = '';

switch (a) {  
    case 1: m = 'Jan'; break;
    case 2: m = 'Feb'; break;
    case 3: m = 'Mar'; break;
    case 4: m = 'Apr'; break;
    case 5: m = 'May'; break;
    case 6: m = 'Jun'; break;
    case 7: m = 'Jul'; break;
    case 8: m = 'Aug'; break;
    case 9: m = 'Sep'; break;
    case 10: m = 'Oct'; break;
    case 11: m = 'Nov'; break;
    case 12: m = 'Dec'; break;
    default: break;
}

document.getElementById("month").html(m);
```

Comment: You need to shift whole code from `var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('checkMonth').value);` and switch case inside your click function. `console.log(m)` or `alert(m)` after switch case and see its value.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Comment: It would be great If you could mark my answer as solution

Answer (score 0):

The code seems a bit noisy and to be honest, I don't get the 'a = year followed by the switch' thing, what can the end-user define for year?

Can you provide us the HTML as well?

Comment: i did edit the code please see and tell me whats wrong !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getMonth(input){
 if(input.length > 0 && (input >= 1 && input <= 12)){
  let months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
  printResult(months[input - 1], true);
 } else {
  printResult('Your input should be a number between 1 and 12.', false);
 }
}

function printResult(output, success){
 document.getElementById("result").style.color = "red";
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
 
 if(success){
  document.getElementById("result").style.color = "green";
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <input id="month-user-input" type="number" />
    <p id="result">Waiting for user input</p>
    <button id="btn-get-month" onclick="getMonth(document.getElementById('month-user-input').value)">check</button>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```